# Estoy tratando marcar o desmarcar checkbox y guardar valor de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, c#

Cuando obtengo el valor 1 y es true y se me muestra el checkbox marcado, lo cual es correcto, doy guardar y se guarda el valor 1, pero si yo desmarco el checkbox y doy guardar, me sigue mandando el valor 1 lo cual es erroneo, me debe guardar el valor 0 por que desmarque el checkbox, independientemente de si esta marcado o no el checkbox siempre me manda el valor 1: dejo condigo, espero me puedan ayudar:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @{var activo = Model.Valor == "1" ? true : false;}
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => activo, new { id = "chkValor"})
                    @*<div id='error_Habilita' name='error_Habilita'>&nbsp;</div>*@
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y en mi controller tengo el siguiente código:

```
 public JsonResult GuardarSolicitudParamCAT(ParametrosCATViewModels guardarSolicitudParamCAT)
{
    Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
    ParametrosCATBC parametrosCATBC = new ParametrosCATBC();

    try
    {
        
        guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Solicitante = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString();
        guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Valor = guardarSolicitudParamCAT.Valor == "true" ? "1" : "0";
        parametrosCATBC.SaveSolicitudParamCAT(guardarSolicitudParamCAT, new Bitacora { PerfilUsuario = Session["Perfil"].ToString(), Usuario = Session["IdUsuario"].ToString() });
                    
        mensaje.Success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        mensaje.Success = false;
        mensaje.ErrorMessage = exception.Message.ToString();
    }
    return Json(mensaje, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué vuelves hacer la misma pregunta? Si necesitas agregar detalles o cosas por el estilo puedes considerar editar la [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/448365/error-al-guardar-valor-de-checkbox-al-marcar-o-desmarcarlo) y no crear un duplicado.

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate que la propiedad que estas leyendo del checkbox es el de **`checked`** y no el **`value`**.